# Spring can't resolve dependencies with an internal class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

today I've met online another poor soul learning Spring. I decided I'll help them. Story as old as Spring, a missing bean in unit tests. I made a quick fix, I put a configuration with the missing bean and it worked, seemed like everything was fine.

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    HelloService getHelloService() {
        return new HelloService();
    }
}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(HelloController.class)
@Import({Config.class})
class HelloControllerIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;


    @Test
    void hello() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = get("/hello");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals("Hello, World", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHelloWithName() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/hello?name=Dan"))
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello, Dan"));
    }
}
```

On the second thought, polluting the public space with additional and very genericly named class is not a good idea, so I decided to put it inside of the class.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(HelloController.class)
@Import({HelloControllerIntTest.Config.class})
class HelloControllerIntTest {

   @Configuration
   static class Config {
    @Bean
    HelloService getHelloService() {
        return new HelloService();
    }
   }

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;


    @Test
    void hello() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = get("/hello");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals("Hello, World", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHelloWithName() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/hello?name=Dan"))
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello, Dan"));
    }
}
```

To my surprise, it doesn't work, 404 error. I put a breakpoint in the `HelloController` and it seems the bean is not constructed at all. Also I peeked into the beans definitions and it seems the first version has 91 beans, and the second 88, so we have missing beans over there.

Any ideas what happened here? Why in the second version Spring ignores HelloController?

Comment: a 404? or an actual Exception?

Comment: @Eugene 404. As I said `HelloController` is missing, so there's no handler to serve the request.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because your `Config` annotation is looking in a sub-package to find the beans but it can no longer find them.

If you annotate your `Config` static class with a `@ComponentScan("package.of.your.helloController")` then your controller it will be found again.

Comment: There is no `@Config` annotation, and the `@Configuration` class involved does not declare component-scanning.